# Eclipse CDT shows ... not resolved errors for ARM neon intrinsics, but produces the binary

Tags: c++, eclipse, arm, neon

I develop ARM-Neon based embedded software for Cortex A8 and A9 processors.
I use Eclipse CDT Luna for development environment.

I opened a project and added

```
#include "arm_neon.h"
```

at the beginning of my main code, and the following flags to both C++ compiler and linker miscellaneous flags part in project settings:

```
-mfloat-abi=softfp -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -mfpu=neon
```

My indexer does not show any error in "#include arm_neon.h" line, but it underlines each neon function I use with red. Produces many "unresolved" error. But when I build the project, it produces an ARM binary and it works well. What may be the problem?

When I have an ACTUAL problem, it is lost among zillions of others...

Comment: Probably not your immediate problem, but it should of course be `#include <arm_neon.h>`.

Comment: Wow! Incredible...It solved my problem. How simple it was...

Comment: Cool - watch out for this in future - often `<>` and `""` are interchangeable, but in some cases it can make an important difference - always use `<>` for system headers and `""` for user headers. I've converted the comments to an answer below now in case it's of benefit to anyone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
#include "arm_neon.h"
```

to:

```
#include <arm_neon.h>
```

Watch out for this in future - often `<>` and `""` are interchangeable, but in some cases it can make an important difference. Always use `<>` for system headers and `""` for user headers.